# Modal Popup loading screen appears after all other code has run

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a web form that takes user input, generates a dynamic SQL query and outputs the result to a gridview.

The SQL could potentially take a while to run, so I made a loading screen using Bootstraps modal popup. The idea being that the loading screen would display while the SQL is running.

However, the loading popup appears **AFTER** the gridview has been populated with the results, which kind of defeats the point of a loading screen!!!

Can anyone give me any ideas as to why this is happening and help me with a potential solution?

**C#**

```
    protected void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Display the loading popup
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowLoading();", true);

        //Declaring the SQL statement to be passed to the database
        SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1 = new SqlDataSource();
        SqlDataSource1.ID = "SqlDataSource1";
        this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource1);
        SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SQL Command Here";
        gvResults.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
        gvResults.DataBind();

    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
    function ShowLoading() {
        $("#btnShowModalLoading").click();
    }
```

**ASPX**

```
<button id="btnShowModalLoading" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg hide" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#modalLoading">
    Open Modal</button>
```

**Modal**

```
<div id="modalLoading" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h2>
                    Please Wait...</h2>
                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because the script to display the modal popup will be sent to the client after all the server side code is executed, as part of the full page response. What you should do is to display the modal first, on the client side, before posting back. You may also put the Grid View into an update panel to implement filling the grid view without navigating away from that current page

Comment: So do I remove the clientscript from my server side code and call the Javascript from the run button by adding onclientclick="ShowRequest()"

Comment: Yes. Exactly. That should work

Comment: Brilliant that worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're registering a ClientStartupScript in your server-side OnClick handler. This means that when the handler finishes and returns its data either via Postback or Ajax, only then will the script run.

You need to attach a client onclick event, e.g. via jQuery or via the `onclientclick` attribute of the button, and that's where you'd put the code to open the modal.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've removed the clientscript line from my server side code and added onclientclick="ShowLoading()" to my run button but that doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: You should reference the Bootstrap API for the version you're using and look at how to directly open a modal instead of having a button click another button which then opens the modal. If you really need two buttons that do the same thing, there are other ways to refactor your javascript so they share the same code. You should also try basic debugging steps like viewing your HTML output to make sure the html <button> has `onclick` and then doing `console.log` or `alert` statements in your `ShowLoading()` function.

Comment: Apologies, it wasn't working due to a spelling mistake. I'll look into the API to see if there is a better way of doing it and post back here my updated code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the response to the request.  In order for this to work you're going to need to have your run button click display the load modal then submit from there in javascript.